# dnsmasq forward dns requests + add domain suffix for not fqdn

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ubuntu-12.04, dnsmasq

I want to use dnsmasq as a DNS forwarder:

for fully qualified domain names it should forward request without change;
for not fully qualified name it should add domain to the name and forward (searching ubuntu -> forward searching ubuntu.mydomain.com).
I tried --expand-domains, --domain, --domain-needed options but they are not what I'm looking for. Is it possible to achieve this behaviour using dnsmasq and how? (maybe other services if not, bind?)

I'd really appreciate any comments and suggestions.

BTW I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via "search" option of the /etc/resolv.conf